# How can I use a random redis command for redisbloom

Tags: perl, redis, bloom-filter

I am using perl Redis.pm for all the sys jobs with redis 
All standard redis commands are available in the module

But for a custom load module , how can I use that in perl

For eg Redisbloom

On command line this works

```
127.0.0.1:6379> bf.add names tom
(integer) 1
```

I am not sure what I can do is a perl script. This does not work

```
my $n = $redis->cmd("bf.add","names","tom");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redis module does not support calling custom commands, as far as I can tell. [Mojo::Redis](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Redis) does.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::Redis;
my $redis = Mojo::Redis->new('redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0')->encoding(undef);
$redis->db->call('bf.add', 'names', 'tom');
```

Note that the encoding attribute is set to `undef` here to match the behavior of the Redis module - if you will be dealing with any non-ascii text data and want it to be automatically encoded and decoded for storage, you can leave it at the default of `UTF-8`.

Comment: That works but there is a problem , everytime I call the "call" method 
2 redis calls are exiecute 

"SELECT" "0"
"bf.add" "names" "tom"

Can I avoid the SELECT , potentially a performance hit

Comment: @Ram That is from calling `->db` because I specified the `0` database explicitly in the URL. You can either remove the explicit `/0` (it is default) or get the `db` object once and reuse it for several commands. `my $db = $redis->db; $db->call(...);` In a long running process you don't want to keep the `db` around forever, it can't reconnect in the case of a disconnection or fork.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try:

```
use Redis;
my $redis = Redis->new;
my $n = $redis->__std_cmd("bf.add", "names", "tom");
```

The Perl client makes using periods in commmand names an impossibility - this seems to work around that.